# Clarification on the properties of double summation in causal inference

Tags: probability, summation, causal-diagrams

Below is the proof along with the causal graph I copied from a textbook about [causal inference by Brady Neal](https://www.bradyneal.com/Introduction_to_Causal_Inference-Dec17_2020-Neal.pdf):

**Claim** Given the causal graph is [Figure A.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hEF5.png), $P(m \mid d o(t))=P(m \mid t)$.

**START OF THE PROOF**

Proof. We first apply the Bayesian network factorization ([Definition 3.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS4IN.png)):
$$
P(w, t, m, y)=P(w) P(t \mid w) P(m \mid t) P(y \mid w, m)
$$

Next, we apply the truncated factorization ([Proposition 4.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzXIK.png)):
$$
P(w, m, y \mid d o(t))=P(w) P(m \mid t) P(y \mid w, m)
$$

Finally, we marginalize out $w$ and $y$ :
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_w \sum_y P(w, m, y \mid d o(t)) & =\sum_w \sum_y P(w) P(m \mid t) P(y \mid w, m) \\
P(m \mid d o(t)) & =\left(\sum_w P(w)\right) P(m \mid t)\left(\sum_y P(y \mid w, m)\right) \\
& =P(m \mid t)
\end{aligned}
$$

**END OF THE PROOF**

What I do no understand is how
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_w \sum_y P(w) P(m \mid t) P(y \mid w, m)
\end{aligned}
$$

becomes

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(\sum_w P(w)\right) P(m \mid t)\left(\sum_y P(y \mid w, m)\right)
\end{aligned}.
$$

My understanding is that $P(w)$ and $P(m\mid t)$ have nothing to do with $\sum_y$, so we can rearrange
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_w \sum_y P(w) P(m \mid t) P(y \mid w, m)
\end{aligned}
$$

into

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_w P(w)P(m \mid t)\left(\sum_y P(y \mid w, m)\right)
\end{aligned}.
$$

But why can $\sum_w P(w)$ be separated from the rest of the expression? Is it some general rule of double summation or is it only applied to this specific case?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: No need to separate the expression. The $\sum_y$ sums to 1 for every $w$ and $m$, so only the $\sum_w P(w)P(m|t)$ remains, and the $P(m|t)$ does not depend on $w$

Comment: Thanks. That is true. But I'm still quite confused about the derivation in the book.

Comment: I have a feeling I'm not being helpful but $$\sum_w P(w) P(m \mid t)\underbrace{\left(\sum_y P(y \mid w, m)\right)}_{=1} = \sum_w P(w) P(m \mid t) = P(m \mid t)\underbrace{\sum_w P(w)}_{=1} = P(m \mid t), $$ so it is indeed correct to put parentheses around $\sum_w P(w)$ because the rest of the expression does not depend on $w$